# How does Rails know that a migration has been up'ed/run?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-migrations

I just loaded a DB dump, and not only it created tables, and loaded the data in those tables, it also up'ed a lot of migrations.

And after running the remaining migrations, running `rake db:migrate:status` tells me that the status of each migration is `UP`, but the migrations have not actually done what they are supposed to do.

For example, I have a migration that creates a table called `notes`. It has been up'ed, and the tables `notes` doesn't exist. So I had to `redo` this migration, but commenting out the code in `self.down` method.

My question is: How can a migration be in `UP` status even though the table it tries to create, hasn't been created in the database. Or I guess, the db dumb that I loaded earlier, has populated `schema_migrations` table in such a way that Rails considers mostly migrations are up, but actually they aren't.

Now, do I need manually need to `rake db:migrate:redo VERSION=xxxxxxx` each migration, or there is a better solution?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Rails adds a table to your schema named `schema_migrations` which stores the timestamp of each migration in a single column. It doesn't show up in the `schema.rb`, but Rails will compare the timestamps in `db/migrate` and the timestamp of `schema.rb` to the values of the `schema_migrations` table to determine which migrations have run.

[image]

Comment: This is true! The source code for this implementation can be found here https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/f47b4236e089b07cb683ee9b7ff8b06111a0ec10/activerecord/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake#L91

Answer (score 1):

Rails uses Rack middleware `ActiveRecord::Migration::CheckPending` to do that.

You can view all Rack middlewares Rails is using by executing `rack middleware` in your console.

Comment: This doesn't answer by question.

Comment: I think I've misunderstood your questions. I think there should be some conflicts in the Rails environment, e.g. you might need to specify the RAILS_ENV=test in case you're trying to create database in test env